# Decorate class hierarchy

Tags: c#, generics, decorator

Given an object graph with multiple classes, how could I get a decorated hierarchical instance where each complex type is also decorated without creating concrete mappings for each type?  For example if I have the following:

```
public class Root {
   public Child FirstBorn {get;set;}
   public Child SecondBorn {get;set;}
}

public class Child {
   public List<Possession> Possessions {get;set;}
}

public class Possession {

}
```

And I would like to have decorate all of the complex types as a document...

```
public class AsDocument<T>
{
    public AsDocument(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
        Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
        Origin = value.GetType().FullName;

    }

    public String Origin { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
}
```

One could Decorate the root class as:

```
var decoratedRoot = new AsDocument<Root>(someRoot);
```

Is there an approach where each complex type would also get decorated?

So...if decoratedRoot was created in that manner...
FirstBorn and SecondBorn would be of type AsDocument and AsDocument

Comment: var decoratedChild = new AsDocument<Child>(someChild); Do you want to avoid specializing like that?

Comment: At this case, `AsDocument<T>` should be inherited from `T`, but it is not allowed by compiler. You can start searching from "Inversion of Control" libraries

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want something like this:

```
public class Root {
   public AsDocument<Child> FirstBorn {get;set;}
   public AsDocument<Child> SecondBorn {get;set;}
}

public class Child {
   public List<AsDocument<Possession>> Possessions {get;set;}
}

public class Possession {

}
```

Comment: This would be the static result.  However, I am looking for something that would be along the lines of a dynamic proxy object.